# Dangers of allowing a db_datareader to run any query?

Tags: sql-server

On a certain site there is report system. The system is based on running SQL queries that are stored in the database. Those queries are executed through a db_datareader user. Generally those queries are written by the site admin. Assuming an attacker managed to get access to site admin account and can add any query he likes to the report system, are there any dangerous ones that he can execute as a db_datareader user? (By dangerous I mean things that can help the attacker gain control of the server or gain SA access to database.)

If there are such queries are there steps I can take to prevent the report db user (the one with db_datareader role) from executing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users with the db_datareader role can only issue SELECT queries against tables and views in the database, and no other kinds of queries.

So while a malicious user might be able to view some data that you don't want him to see, he can not do anything that is dangerous by your definition.

Comment: That's reassuring. If someone somehow managed to get access to a site admin account, he would already have access to all the information from the DB, so a more elaborate way to do the same, would not hurt the site more.